# ArcGIS Identify Window

Tags: arcmap, identity

I have been using ArcGIS ArcMap's Identity Tool to find out what's found in a selected polygon (AOI) from multiple *visible* layers.  The results gets displayed in the Identify Window.  How can I get the result directly to text format without going through *copy selected fields*? Does anyone know the code behind the Identify Window?

Comment: The developers certainly have access to the source, but you'd be better off writing a tool to do what you need.

Comment: To do this I would write a Python AddIn using ArcPy.  An ArcObjects developer would most likely take a different route.

Comment: Vince & PolyGeo thanks.  But crafting a script will bring me to the same identify window